# ASP.net needs Body element around existing model

Tags: asp.net, rest

I have a model all set up.
In my controller it looks like

```
[Route("thingy")]
public IHttpActionResult Post(ThingyModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var results = manager.SomeCallback(model);
    if (!results)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

In my models I have validation and everything.

Turns out, in the 11th hour I found out that instead of

```json
{
    "example_attribute": "example_value",
    … // other attributes and values
}
```

I actually need

```json
{
    "body" : {
        "example_attribute": "example_value",
        … // other attributes and values
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to add this body element around my valid model

Answer (score 0):

What was needed was I needed to make a copy of my `ThingyModel.cs` file and rename it to `ThingyBodyModel.cs`.

In `ThingyModel.cs` I replaced all my existing JsonProperties with

```
    public class ThingyModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Model for Thingy API callback
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "body")]
        public ThingyBodyModel Body { get; set; }
    }
```

This allowed me to fix-up all my validators by just adding `.Body` and to change the call shown for `manager.SomeCallback(model)` to this:

```
var valuePairs = MethodToParseValues(model.Body.MemberValueThing);
```

where before it was just `var valuePairs = MethodToParseValues(model.MemberValueThing);`